# How do I find out if my aircraft satisfies a particular ICAO equipment/surveillance/PBN code?

Tags: aircraft-systems, icao

I have a new, G1000-equipped C172S that just arrived, and I’m trying to figure out the specific ICAO equipment/surveillance/PBN/etc. codes for the aircraft.

I’ve been trying to find out where to find this information via Google, but I haven’t found much that tells me where, specifically, to find this information for my specific aircraft.

Can someone please elaborate, in detail (“ELI5”), where I find this information?

For Example: Where do I find out if my aircraft has GNSS, SBAS, APV with SBAS, RNAV 1, RNAV 5, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25275/62) has a generic answer; [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/88172/62) is specifically about the C172 and G1000.

Comment: Not authoritative, but for the 2019-2021 model C172S/G1000 planes at my flight school, I was told to use ICAO Equipment B,G,R,S; ICAO Surveillance B2,S; and ICAO PBN B2,C2,D2 in ForeFlight.